# Convert a list with multiple lines into data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have list as given below

```
['7237      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.239999E-07  -3.733407E-07   2.212587E-07',
 '7238      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            4.846863E-06  -9.922069E-07   8.458463E-06',
 '7239      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.073667E-05  -3.717125E-06   2.890958E-05',
 '7240      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            8.920388E-05  -7.419183E-06   6.471878E-05',
 '7241      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.832756E-04  -1.062274E-05   1.152823E-04',
 '7242      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.104847E-04  -1.263393E-05   1.780886E-04',
 '7243      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            4.645259E-04  -1.285412E-05   2.493027E-04',
 '7244      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            6.359626E-04  -1.083016E-05   3.242427E-04',
 '7245      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            8.127339E-04  -6.187393E-06   3.976933E-04',
 '7246      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            9.805798E-04   1.373597E-06   4.641845E-04',
 '7247      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.123478E-03   1.204513E-05   5.182628E-04',
 '7248      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.224244E-03   2.590691E-05   5.547877E-04',
 '7249      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.265126E-03   4.292454E-05   5.691787E-04',
 '7250      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.228418E-03   6.293558E-05   5.576411E-04',
 '7251      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.097197E-03   8.563578E-05   5.173817E-04',
 '7252      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            8.560375E-04   1.105952E-04   4.467830E-04',
 '7253      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            4.916305E-04   1.372820E-04   3.454892E-04',
 '7254      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -6.634202E-06   1.650501E-04   2.144534E-04',
 '7255      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -6.459849E-04   1.931538E-04   5.597509E-05',
 '7256      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.429897E-03   2.208132E-04  -1.264037E-04',
 '7257      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.357971E-03   2.472607E-04  -3.280706E-04',
 '7258      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -3.425660E-03   2.716504E-04  -5.434573E-04',
 '7259      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -4.623938E-03   2.931546E-04  -7.662221E-04',
 '7260      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -5.939634E-03   3.110625E-04  -9.895572E-04',
 '7261      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -7.355830E-03   3.247523E-04  -1.206506E-03',
 '7262      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -8.851902E-03   3.335908E-04  -1.410110E-03',
 '7263      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.040373E-02   3.370576E-04  -1.593686E-03',
 '7264      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.198441E-02   3.348549E-04  -1.751147E-03',
 '7265      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.356535E-02   3.268293E-04  -1.877329E-03',
 '7266      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.511621E-02   3.128250E-04  -1.967968E-03',
 '7267      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.660536E-02   2.928187E-04  -2.019983E-03',
 '7268      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.800119E-02   2.671044E-04  -2.031644E-03',
 '7269      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.927284E-02   2.360256E-04  -2.002611E-03',
 '7270      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.039046E-02   1.999231E-04  -1.934050E-03',
 '7271      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.132561E-02   1.593439E-04  -1.828405E-03',
 '7272      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.205253E-02   1.149674E-04  -1.689621E-03',
 '7273      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.254844E-02   6.753532E-05  -1.522828E-03',
 '7274      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.279390E-02   1.774249E-05  -1.334391E-03',
 '7275      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.277315E-02  -3.355248E-05  -1.131589E-03',
 '7276      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.247470E-02  -8.549847E-05  -9.224852E-04',
 '7277      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.189133E-02  -1.372712E-04  -7.157133E-04',
 '7278      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.102014E-02  -1.880403E-04  -5.202099E-04',
 '7279      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.986319E-02  -2.369646E-04  -3.449890E-04',
 '7280      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.842674E-02  -2.833290E-04  -1.988935E-04',
 '7281      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.672131E-02  -3.264680E-04  -9.035443E-05',
 '7282      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.476152E-02  -3.656876E-04  -2.717614E-05',
 '7283      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.256647E-02  -4.004281E-04  -1.629253E-05',
 '7284      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.015823E-02  -4.303372E-04  -6.362354E-05',
 '7285      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -7.561759E-03  -4.550700E-04  -1.739045E-04',
 '7286      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -4.804914E-03  -4.742260E-04  -3.505420E-04',
 '7287      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.918424E-03  -4.876927E-04  -5.954905E-04',
 '7288      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.066243E-03  -4.954925E-04  -9.092903E-04',
 '7289      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            4.116441E-03  -4.976777E-04  -1.290999E-03',
 '7290      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            7.198711E-03  -4.941604E-04  -1.738162E-03',
 '7291      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.027845E-02  -4.851927E-04  -2.246741E-03',
 '7292      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.332275E-02  -4.711772E-04  -2.811515E-03',
 '7293      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.629910E-02  -4.523546E-04  -3.425953E-03',
 '7294      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.917596E-02  -4.289898E-04  -4.082270E-03',
 '7295      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.192276E-02  -4.014440E-04  -4.771517E-03',
 '7296      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.451170E-02  -3.703599E-04  -5.484174E-03',
 '7297      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.691683E-02  -3.361543E-04  -6.209807E-03',
 '7298      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.911462E-02  -2.990009E-04  -6.937434E-03',
 '7299      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.108352E-02  -2.596472E-04  -7.655686E-03',
 '7300      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.280532E-02  -2.184632E-04  -8.353029E-03',
 '7301      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.426476E-02  -1.759197E-04  -9.017997E-03',
 '7302      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.544938E-02  -1.324717E-04  -9.639216E-03',
 '7303      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.634929E-02  -8.843491E-05  -1.020561E-02',
 '7304      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.695816E-02  -4.435903E-05  -1.070667E-02',
 '7305      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.727290E-02  -6.557301E-07  -1.113260E-02',
 '7306      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.729299E-02   4.243319E-05  -1.147457E-02',
 '7307      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.702102E-02   8.445788E-05  -1.172442E-02',
 '7308      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.646299E-02   1.251660E-04  -1.187534E-02',
 '7309      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.562659E-02   1.642386E-04  -1.192169E-02',
 '7310      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.452363E-02   2.017011E-04  -1.185930E-02',
 '7311      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.316473E-02   2.369071E-04  -1.168458E-02',
 '7312      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.156928E-02   2.713725E-04  -1.139660E-02',
 '7313      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.973885E-02   3.023380E-04  -1.099048E-02',
 '7314      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.771325E-02   3.401653E-04  -1.047144E-02',
 '7315      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.543261E-02   3.599349E-04  -9.820674E-03',
 '7316      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.303620E-02   4.483988E-04  -9.053966E-03',
 '7317      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.015015E-02   3.680175E-04  -8.111417E-03',
 '7318      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.734203E-02   8.962593E-04  -6.898442E-03',
 '7319      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.293533E-02  -1.037660E-04  -5.614001E-03',
 '7320      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            6.715167E-03   2.935881E-03  -1.681344E-03',
 '7321      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.925452E-06  -9.375238E-06  -2.608838E-06',
 '7322      G     -6.823360E-05   1.435983E-05   6.082949E-05   7.756484E-06  -2.577170E-05   1.456521E-05',
 '7323      G     -1.968978E-04   6.570999E-05   2.270545E-04   4.888926E-05  -5.037818E-05   4.911626E-05',
 '7324      G     -3.873697E-04   1.604050E-04   5.172742E-04   1.267640E-04  -7.556767E-05   1.001224E-04',
 '7325      G     -6.331790E-04   2.944199E-04   9.284513E-04   2.409916E-04  -9.749331E-05   1.644443E-04',
 '7326      G     -9.221990E-04   4.581800E-04   1.442364E-03   3.869134E-04  -1.133447E-04   2.379998E-04',
 '7327      G     -1.238365E-03   6.386000E-04   2.028668E-03   5.564194E-04  -1.209288E-04   3.159248E-04',
 '7328      G     -1.563143E-03   8.205113E-04   2.647201E-03   7.385519E-04  -1.184654E-04   3.928505E-04',
 '7329      G     -1.876570E-03   9.876314E-04   3.249530E-03   9.199430E-04  -1.045441E-04   4.631632E-04',
 '7330      G     -2.158222E-03   1.123439E-03   3.780576E-03   1.085245E-03  -7.814648E-05   5.212718E-04',
 '7331      G     -2.388134E-03   1.212101E-03   4.180369E-03   1.217595E-03  -3.870377E-05   5.618648E-04',
 '7332      G     -2.547863E-03   1.239300E-03   4.386411E-03   1.299286E-03   1.387789E-05   5.802092E-04',
 '7333      G     -2.621319E-03   1.193072E-03   4.335866E-03   1.312376E-03   7.919144E-05   5.723748E-04',
 '7334      G     -2.595507E-03   1.064444E-03   3.967895E-03   1.239348E-03   1.563191E-04   5.354343E-04',
 '7335      G     -2.461227E-03   8.481031E-04   3.226334E-03   1.063860E-03   2.438154E-04   4.676474E-04',
 '7336      G     -2.213612E-03   5.428195E-04   2.062120E-03   7.714584E-04   3.397792E-04   3.685738E-04']
```

I want to convert this list into a Data frame.

Comment: Good luck with the task! Feel free to ask a question if you have any..

Comment: No its a list, I have added " " just to highlight

Comment: Use `split()` to convert each string to a list. Then you can easily convert the 2-dimensional list to a dataframe.

Comment: Did that start out as a file? You could use `pandas.read_csv` with a regex separator of `r"\s+"`.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([l.split() for l in lst])`?

Comment: Thanks! The code is working fine

Answer (score 3):

The below works:

```
import pandas as pd
lst = ['7237      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.239999E-07  -3.733407E-07   2.212587E-07',
 '7238      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            4.846863E-06  -9.922069E-07   8.458463E-06',
 '7239      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.073667E-05  -3.717125E-06   2.890958E-05',
 '7240      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            8.920388E-05  -7.419183E-06   6.471878E-05',
 '7241      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.832756E-04  -1.062274E-05   1.152823E-04',
 '7242      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.104847E-04  -1.263393E-05   1.780886E-04',
 '7243      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            4.645259E-04  -1.285412E-05   2.493027E-04',
 '7244      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            6.359626E-04  -1.083016E-05   3.242427E-04',
 '7245      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            8.127339E-04  -6.187393E-06   3.976933E-04',
 '7246      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            9.805798E-04   1.373597E-06   4.641845E-04',
 '7247      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.123478E-03   1.204513E-05   5.182628E-04',
 '7248      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.224244E-03   2.590691E-05   5.547877E-04',
 '7249      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.265126E-03   4.292454E-05   5.691787E-04',
 '7250      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.228418E-03   6.293558E-05   5.576411E-04',
 '7251      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.097197E-03   8.563578E-05   5.173817E-04',
 '7252      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            8.560375E-04   1.105952E-04   4.467830E-04',
 '7253      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            4.916305E-04   1.372820E-04   3.454892E-04',
 '7254      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -6.634202E-06   1.650501E-04   2.144534E-04',
 '7255      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -6.459849E-04   1.931538E-04   5.597509E-05',
 '7256      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.429897E-03   2.208132E-04  -1.264037E-04',
 '7257      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.357971E-03   2.472607E-04  -3.280706E-04',
 '7258      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -3.425660E-03   2.716504E-04  -5.434573E-04',
 '7259      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -4.623938E-03   2.931546E-04  -7.662221E-04',
 '7260      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -5.939634E-03   3.110625E-04  -9.895572E-04',
 '7261      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -7.355830E-03   3.247523E-04  -1.206506E-03',
 '7262      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -8.851902E-03   3.335908E-04  -1.410110E-03',
 '7263      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.040373E-02   3.370576E-04  -1.593686E-03',
 '7264      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.198441E-02   3.348549E-04  -1.751147E-03',
 '7265      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.356535E-02   3.268293E-04  -1.877329E-03',
 '7266      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.511621E-02   3.128250E-04  -1.967968E-03',
 '7267      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.660536E-02   2.928187E-04  -2.019983E-03',
 '7268      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.800119E-02   2.671044E-04  -2.031644E-03',
 '7269      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.927284E-02   2.360256E-04  -2.002611E-03',
 '7270      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.039046E-02   1.999231E-04  -1.934050E-03',
 '7271      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.132561E-02   1.593439E-04  -1.828405E-03',
 '7272      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.205253E-02   1.149674E-04  -1.689621E-03',
 '7273      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.254844E-02   6.753532E-05  -1.522828E-03',
 '7274      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.279390E-02   1.774249E-05  -1.334391E-03',
 '7275      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.277315E-02  -3.355248E-05  -1.131589E-03',
 '7276      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.247470E-02  -8.549847E-05  -9.224852E-04',
 '7277      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.189133E-02  -1.372712E-04  -7.157133E-04',
 '7278      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -2.102014E-02  -1.880403E-04  -5.202099E-04',
 '7279      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.986319E-02  -2.369646E-04  -3.449890E-04',
 '7280      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.842674E-02  -2.833290E-04  -1.988935E-04',
 '7281      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.672131E-02  -3.264680E-04  -9.035443E-05',
 '7282      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.476152E-02  -3.656876E-04  -2.717614E-05',
 '7283      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.256647E-02  -4.004281E-04  -1.629253E-05',
 '7284      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.015823E-02  -4.303372E-04  -6.362354E-05',
 '7285      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -7.561759E-03  -4.550700E-04  -1.739045E-04',
 '7286      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -4.804914E-03  -4.742260E-04  -3.505420E-04',
 '7287      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.918424E-03  -4.876927E-04  -5.954905E-04',
 '7288      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.066243E-03  -4.954925E-04  -9.092903E-04',
 '7289      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            4.116441E-03  -4.976777E-04  -1.290999E-03',
 '7290      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            7.198711E-03  -4.941604E-04  -1.738162E-03',
 '7291      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.027845E-02  -4.851927E-04  -2.246741E-03',
 '7292      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.332275E-02  -4.711772E-04  -2.811515E-03',
 '7293      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.629910E-02  -4.523546E-04  -3.425953E-03',
 '7294      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.917596E-02  -4.289898E-04  -4.082270E-03',
 '7295      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.192276E-02  -4.014440E-04  -4.771517E-03',
 '7296      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.451170E-02  -3.703599E-04  -5.484174E-03',
 '7297      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.691683E-02  -3.361543E-04  -6.209807E-03',
 '7298      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.911462E-02  -2.990009E-04  -6.937434E-03',
 '7299      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.108352E-02  -2.596472E-04  -7.655686E-03',
 '7300      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.280532E-02  -2.184632E-04  -8.353029E-03',
 '7301      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.426476E-02  -1.759197E-04  -9.017997E-03',
 '7302      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.544938E-02  -1.324717E-04  -9.639216E-03',
 '7303      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.634929E-02  -8.843491E-05  -1.020561E-02',
 '7304      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.695816E-02  -4.435903E-05  -1.070667E-02',
 '7305      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.727290E-02  -6.557301E-07  -1.113260E-02',
 '7306      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.729299E-02   4.243319E-05  -1.147457E-02',
 '7307      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.702102E-02   8.445788E-05  -1.172442E-02',
 '7308      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.646299E-02   1.251660E-04  -1.187534E-02',
 '7309      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.562659E-02   1.642386E-04  -1.192169E-02',
 '7310      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.452363E-02   2.017011E-04  -1.185930E-02',
 '7311      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.316473E-02   2.369071E-04  -1.168458E-02',
 '7312      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            3.156928E-02   2.713725E-04  -1.139660E-02',
 '7313      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.973885E-02   3.023380E-04  -1.099048E-02',
 '7314      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.771325E-02   3.401653E-04  -1.047144E-02',
 '7315      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.543261E-02   3.599349E-04  -9.820674E-03',
 '7316      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.303620E-02   4.483988E-04  -9.053966E-03',
 '7317      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            2.015015E-02   3.680175E-04  -8.111417E-03',
 '7318      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.734203E-02   8.962593E-04  -6.898442E-03',
 '7319      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            1.293533E-02  -1.037660E-04  -5.614001E-03',
 '7320      G      0.0            0.0            0.0            6.715167E-03   2.935881E-03  -1.681344E-03',
 '7321      G      0.0            0.0            0.0           -1.925452E-06  -9.375238E-06  -2.608838E-06',
 '7322      G     -6.823360E-05   1.435983E-05   6.082949E-05   7.756484E-06  -2.577170E-05   1.456521E-05',
 '7323      G     -1.968978E-04   6.570999E-05   2.270545E-04   4.888926E-05  -5.037818E-05   4.911626E-05',
 '7324      G     -3.873697E-04   1.604050E-04   5.172742E-04   1.267640E-04  -7.556767E-05   1.001224E-04',
 '7325      G     -6.331790E-04   2.944199E-04   9.284513E-04   2.409916E-04  -9.749331E-05   1.644443E-04',
 '7326      G     -9.221990E-04   4.581800E-04   1.442364E-03   3.869134E-04  -1.133447E-04   2.379998E-04',
 '7327      G     -1.238365E-03   6.386000E-04   2.028668E-03   5.564194E-04  -1.209288E-04   3.159248E-04',
 '7328      G     -1.563143E-03   8.205113E-04   2.647201E-03   7.385519E-04  -1.184654E-04   3.928505E-04',
 '7329      G     -1.876570E-03   9.876314E-04   3.249530E-03   9.199430E-04  -1.045441E-04   4.631632E-04',
 '7330      G     -2.158222E-03   1.123439E-03   3.780576E-03   1.085245E-03  -7.814648E-05   5.212718E-04',
 '7331      G     -2.388134E-03   1.212101E-03   4.180369E-03   1.217595E-03  -3.870377E-05   5.618648E-04',
 '7332      G     -2.547863E-03   1.239300E-03   4.386411E-03   1.299286E-03   1.387789E-05   5.802092E-04',
 '7333      G     -2.621319E-03   1.193072E-03   4.335866E-03   1.312376E-03   7.919144E-05   5.723748E-04',
 '7334      G     -2.595507E-03   1.064444E-03   3.967895E-03   1.239348E-03   1.563191E-04   5.354343E-04',
 '7335      G     -2.461227E-03   8.481031E-04   3.226334E-03   1.063860E-03   2.438154E-04   4.676474E-04',
 '7336      G     -2.213612E-03   5.428195E-04   2.062120E-03   7.714584E-04   3.397792E-04   3.685738E-04']

lst = [x.split() for x in lst]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)
```

output

```
       0  1              2  ...              5              6              7
0   7237  G            0.0  ...   1.239999E-07  -3.733407E-07   2.212587E-07
1   7238  G            0.0  ...   4.846863E-06  -9.922069E-07   8.458463E-06
2   7239  G            0.0  ...   3.073667E-05  -3.717125E-06   2.890958E-05
3   7240  G            0.0  ...   8.920388E-05  -7.419183E-06   6.471878E-05
4   7241  G            0.0  ...   1.832756E-04  -1.062274E-05   1.152823E-04
5   7242  G            0.0  ...   3.104847E-04  -1.263393E-05   1.780886E-04
6   7243  G            0.0  ...   4.645259E-04  -1.285412E-05   2.493027E-04
7   7244  G            0.0  ...   6.359626E-04  -1.083016E-05   3.242427E-04
8   7245  G            0.0  ...   8.127339E-04  -6.187393E-06   3.976933E-04
9   7246  G            0.0  ...   9.805798E-04   1.373597E-06   4.641845E-04
10  7247  G            0.0  ...   1.123478E-03   1.204513E-05   5.182628E-04
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ...!